# this equals window in requestAnimationFrame callback

Tags: javascript

I have some gallery code using the revealing module pattern:

```
window.jdiGallery = (function () { //Structure from http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-first-javascript-library--net-26796
var instance = null;

function Gallery (nodeList, options) {
    this.settings = this.extend({
        'transitionSpeed': 100, //in ms
        'slideSpeed': 5000
            }, options);
        this.requestAnimationId; //We need this handle for canceling the RAF
        this.start = null; //To help determine how far we are between transitions
         for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++ ) 
            this.instances[i] = this.init(nodeList[i]);
         }


    Gallery.prototype.init = function(el){
        var slideEls = el.querySelectorAll('* > .nd-slide');
        var slides = [];
            //this is equal to the Gallery instance
        for(var i = 0; i < slideEls.length - 1; i++)
            slides.push(new Slide(slideEls[i], i, this.settings["inTransition"], this.settings["outTransition"]));
    }       
    Gallery.prototype.moveToNext = function(timestamp){
        var progress;
        if (this.start === null) //this is equal to window
            this.start = timestamp;
        progress = timestamp - this.start;

        if (progress > 5000) {
            console.log('moving to next');
            this.start = null;
            requestAnimationFrame(this.moveToNext);
        }
    }

    return {
        create: function (selector, options) {
            //creation code omitted for brevity            
            instance = new Gallery(els, options);

            this.requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(instance.moveToNext);
        },
```

When `create` is called, it eventually calls `Gallery.init()`. In that function, `this` is equal to the instance of `Gallery`.

I then pass `Gallery.moveToNext()` as a callback to my `requestFrameAnimation`. When we move into `moveToNext`, the value of `this` is `window`. Why is it not referencing the `Gallery` as I had expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a common problem in JavaScript. The `this` binding in JavaScript is dependent on *how the function is called*.

The general rule is (for browsers):

- if a function is called from a bare identifier, `this` is set to `window`

  ```
  > var foo = function() { console.log(this); };
  > foo();
  Window
  ```
- if a function is called directly from an object, `this` is set to the object

  ```
  > var bar = {
  >     bar: function() { console.log(this); }
  > };
  > bar.foo();
  Object
  ```
- if a function is called with either `.call()` or `.apply()`, `this` is set to whatever is passed in as the first argument

In this case, `requestAnimationFrame` only has a reference to the `moveToNext` function itself, not on its context. One solution is to use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.moveToNext.bind(this));
```

In addition, you can cache the bound version inside of `Gallery.prototype.init`

```
this.moveToNextBound = this.moveToNext.bind(this);
```

You can also just use an anonymous function, but to do so you will need to rebind `this` to another variable.

```
var self = this;
requestAnimationFrame(function() { self.moveToNext.apply(arguments); });
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.moveToNext` passes the bare function, with no context. The fact that you took it from `this` makes no difference.

Use `this.moveToNext.bind(this)`

Comment: FYI you may need the polyfill from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for older browsers that don't natively have `bind()`.